# Ler um arquivo txt e colocar cada caractere em uma posição de um array em C

Tags: c, c++

Tentei o código abaixo, porém não deu certo

O grande problema é o fscanf colocar cada caractere do texto em uma posição do array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int a;
char texto[1000];

FILE *file;
file = fopen("texto.txt", "r");

//fscanf(file, " %c", &texto);
fscanf(file, " %c", texto);

if (file == NULL) {
printf("Arquivo nao pode ser aberto\n");
return 0;
}


a=0;
do{
printf("%c", texto[a]);
a++;
} while (a<1000);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <iostream>

//using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int a;
    char texto[1000];

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("texto.txt", "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Arquivo nao pode ser aberto\n");
        return 0;
    }

    a=0;
    char ch;
    while( (ch=fgetc(file))!= EOF ){
        texto[a]=ch; //Aqui cada caractere é colocado no array
        a++;
    }
    texto[a]='\0';

    fclose(file);

    int tamanho = strlen(texto); //Define o tamanho do texto que foi lido
    a=0;
    do{
        printf("%c", texto[a]);
        a++;
    } while (a<tamanho); //Exibe apenas o que foi lido

}
```

Comment: Você esqueceu de pôr um `'\0'` depois do último caractere copiado do .txt; dependendo dos valores previamente existentes na pilha, isso pode fazer com que o `strlen(texto)` emita uma violação de proteção (GPF, Segfault, etc.)

Comment: Obrigado, adicionei na resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente isso que eu estava precisando.

Answer (score 1):

Um outra variante, tirando partido do formato string do `fscanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char texto[1000];
  FILE *file;

  if((file = fopen("texto.txt", "r")) == NULL){
     fprintf(stderr,"Erro na abertura \n");
     return 1;                        // codigo de erro (dif. de 0)
  }
  fscanf(file,"%1000[^\f]",texto);    // ler até formfeed ou fim de ficheiro
  printf("%s",texto);
  return 0;                           // 0 -- sucesso
}
```

- `%1000[^\f]` - ler enquanto não for `\f` ou fim de ficheiro, sem exceder 1000 caracteres;
- Normalmente a convenção de valor a retornar do `main` é: ok - 0; erro - ≠ 0
- 10m a indentar o código, poupam 20 no psiquiatra ☺